# How does one create a box/violin plot in ggplot with numeric x values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, boxplot, violin-plot

I would like to create a box or violin plot from 2D numerical data much like the one given in Figure 1A and 1B here ([Goodman, et al., Science, 2003](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/342/6157/475.long)) and given below:

[image: 2D boxplot]

Is there an intuitive way to do this in ggplot2 given the x-y data?

Essentially, I think I need to first bin on x-data and then summarize the y data for plotting, but I don't have a good idea of how I might leverage ggplot functions to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided example data, I am showing a basic example using random data.
You can create breaks to group your data using the function `cut` and then `boxplot` to create the chart.

> Base

```
set.seed(12)
y <- rnorm(1000)
x <- rnorm(1000)
rng <- seq(-3, 3, 0.5)
boxplot(y ~ cut(x, breaks = rng), las = 2)
```

[image]

> Using ggplot2

```
set.seed(12)
y <- rnorm(1000)
x <- rnorm(1000)
df <- data.frame(x = cut(x, breaks=rng), y= y)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x= x , y= y)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = x))
```

[image]